# When I use generics to constrain an interface, why can strings be compiled

Tags: javascript, typescript

[image]

Is there an implicit operation for the ts parser? Why can the prototype methods and properties of string be inherited?

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image.

Comment: A string has a length property and a [big method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/big), why wouldn't it compile? TypeScript is *structurally* typed. Also it's unclear what you think is being inherited here.

Comment: Is there an implicit operation in the process of compiling strings? For the interface, I understand that it can only act on the object, is it wrong to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in the title, "abc123" in JS is a String instance, which has properties `length` and `big()`, this fits the interface so it is valid to say that "abc123" extends `Lengthwise`.

> Is there an implicit operation for the ts parser? Why can the prototype methods and properties of string be inherited?

They're not inherited, they just happen to pass your interface. Inside the function you won't be able to use anything aside from `arg.length` and `arg.big()`. Trying to use more string functions inside the function itself will fail to compile (if your settings are strict enough) but outside the function you may do as you please.

Comment: But length and big are the methods on the string prototype. For ‘123’, its type is string, and the interface declaration acts on object. I know there are some errors in my understanding, but I have not found a theory to prove

Comment: Why have the attributes and methods on the prototype been verified? Where did this step take place?